# Expressjs language library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to make a language module for expressjs. Something like codeigniters language class. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

So that user can choose a language and the appropriate language file gets loaded. I am trying to figure out how to accomplish that in expressjs. Or are there any modules out there? Any thoughts or recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of [i18n modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-i18n) you can use in your application, but you can create your own if you want.

For example create a folder /languages and inside it create en.js, fr.js etc

**it.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "name": "nome",
  "age": "eta",
  .. etc
}
```

The important thing is to set a default language and make a language select bar somewhere in your site. When the user chooses another language (and not English) in your app you do something like this:

```
app.get('/lang/:ln', function (req, res, next) {
  // remember the user's chosen language
  req.session.language = req.params.ln;
});
```

Then you can have a language helper function like so:

```
translate = function (language, text) {
  // language array contains all the languages
  return language_array[language].text;
}
// example: translate(req.session.language, "age")
```

Comment: Sweet :) Thanks for taking the time. You've answered a lot of my questions today :)

Comment: I plan on doing so every day :) Best of luck!